# Passing JSON-encoded variable from PHP to Javascript via POST

Tags: php, javascript, json, post

I have an multi-dimensional array that I want to send to a PHP script with a Javascript that parses the JSON data and plot it on Google Maps. I'm trying to simulate it using forms:

```
<?php
$jsontest = array(
    0 => array(
        'plate_no' => 'abc111',
        'longlat' => array(121.003895,14.631563),
        'info' => 'first item'
        ),
    1 => array(
        'plate_no' => 'abc222',
        'longlat' => array(121.103895,14.731563),
        'info' => 'second item'
        )
    );
$jsonarray = json_encode($jsontest);
?>
<form action="json-target.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="jsonarray" value="<?php echo $jsonarray; ?>" id="jsonarray">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
</form>
```

json-target.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    print "The value of \$_POST is ";
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And the output of `$_POST` is `Array ( [jsonarray] => [{ )`. I wanted to pass the contents of the `$jsonarray` variable to a Javascript function (please see update below).

**UPDATE:** I also have a simple Javascript that's supposed to parse the value received from `$_POST` and post the value via `alert()`:

```
<script src="/js/json2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var json = JSON.parse(<?php echo $_POST['jsonarray'] ?>);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
        alert(json[i]); 
     }
</script>
```

But the output is mangled with backslash characters.

```
var json = JSON.parse([{\"plate_no\":\"abc111\",\"longlat\":[121.003895,14.631563],\"info\":\"first item\"},{\"plate_no\":\"abc222\",\"longlat\":[121.103895,14.731563],\"info\":\"second item\"}]);
```

What's a better way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JSON encoding makes extensive use of quotes.  By simply outputting a JSON encoded string into your HTML `value` attribute, the quotes will interfere with the markup.  They need to be escaped to be put into the HTML.  Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="jsonarray" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($jsonarray,ENT_QUOTES); ?>" id="jsonarray">
```

Edit:  In response to your update, I'm not sure what your JSON.parse is supposed to be doing.  Anything encoded with `json_encode()` in PHP is technically a valid Javascript object, and doesn't need to be parsed any further.  If I had an object named `$obj` with a name property of 'hello', I could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var o = <?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>;
alert(o.name);
</script>
```

and get an alert saying 'hello'.  The output of json_encode is a perfectly suitable javascript object.

The fact that the output of your `$_POST` array has been escaped with slashes leads me to think that perhaps your [magic_quotes_gpc](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) directive is set to be on.  If that's the case, you'll have to unescape your $_POST variables with `stripslashes()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the output in json-target.php but now the JSON object is mangled. Am I doing the right approach?

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to find the answer. Try:

```
var json = JSON.parse(<?php echo stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']) ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

var json=JSON.parse($('#jsonarray').val());
alert (json.plate_no[0]);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your answer. Thank you!