# PHP Passing Array of Objects to Javascript

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert php array to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript-array)
>   [passing PHP objects to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351949/passing-php-objects-to-javascript)

Greetings Stackoverflow

I'm in quite a problem, I want to pass an array of objects from PHP to Javascript for processing. How could I do this. Tnx in advance

Comment: you need [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: did you search Stackoverflow before asking the question? -- look at the "related" list in the side panel; this question has been asked dozens of times already.

Comment: yes i had sir.. other posts did not say how to convert php object to javascript object

Answer (score 2):

Often this is done using an Ajax call to your PHP app, and have PHP generate JSON with the data being sent for processing (see [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

I've also seen PHP programs generate the JavaScript with the data encoded directly in the script, but I would *not* recommend this approach.

Answer (score 2):

When echoing the javascript in the view, you can use `echo json_encode($array)` to convert the PHP array to JSON which can then be inserted into a javascript variable.

Comment: ... on recent versions of PHP.

Comment: ah, if only my web host had that... :(

Comment: @Alnitak Ah, another web host in the dark ages. There's a pure PHP version too https://github.com/stetsenko/code/blob/master/json_encode.php

Comment: But sir, how do I maintain the propoerties of the objects I have passed using json_encode? I have tried doing json_enode but the new array cannot access the properties of the object i just passed..