# How to set javascript variable to php session variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, session-variables

Whats the best way to do this?

I have this `$_SESSION["sessionOpentok"]` I need to set to  this java script var `var session_id`

Security isn't an issue, its okay for the end user to be able to see this session id.

I have heard of AJAX calls, json encode, delimiters, php echo, php print.

None seems to work. echo and print do not work due to quote being in the session variable.

JSON encode encodes this the number to a null.

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing PHP objects to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351949/passing-php-objects-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, just `var session_id = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['sessionOpentok']); ?>;` should do it.

However, you mayhave an encoding problem if you're getting null. Try:

```
var session_id = <?php echo json_encode(utf8_encode($_SESSION['sessionOpentok'])); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the string before echoing it:

```
var session_id = '<?php echo addslashes($_SESSION["sessionOpentok"]) ?>';
```

This might not work depending on how you plan to use the session_id variable as the strings won't match.