# JavaScript Object -> AJAX -> wp_options -> echo theObject?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been trying to solve this using various methods like `JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse`, `json_encode()`, `json_decode()`, `stripslashes()`, `find and replace`, etc, etc.

But I can't figure out where and if to encode the JS object to get it back from the database intact.

Here is what I'm doing at the moment:

**1. Send the JS object via ajax to the WP plugin:**

```
var data = {
    action : 'store_object',
    obj: myObject
};
$.post(ajaxurl, data).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

**2. Save the object in the WP plugin's options:**

```
$myObject = $_POST['obj'];
$options = $this->get_admin_options();
$options['settings'] = $myObject;

update_option($this->admin_options_name, $options);
```

**3. Print the saved object as a JavaScript object:**

```
$options = $this->get_admin_options();

?>
<script>
;(function ($, window, document, undefined ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#el').pluginName(<?php echo stripslashes(json_encode($options['settings'])); ?>);
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

The contents of myObject may contain HTML code or special characters, and this is where the problem comes from. I can't figure out how to cover all corner cases. For example, the code above will translate this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
Hello!
This is a new line.
```

Into this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
Hello!n
This is a new line.n
```

The HTML renders properly, but the \n symbol does not.

So, what is the safest way to do something like this?

**JS Object -> ajax -> wp database -> echo the object as a JS Object**

Comment: `$myObject = $_POST['obj'];`

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6352070/870729